# Need a library for HTTP/HTML network programming in C/C++ or Python

Tags: c++, python, html, c, networking

I don't know that much about network programming, but I am experienced in programming (C/C++, Assembly, Lisp, etc.) and know some basic HTML and Javascript.
I need a good library that can be used for making programs that can

- scan (and parse) an HTML file.
- fill out forms and choose radio buttons
- follow links to open other pages
- submit filled out forms
- bypass captcha (just kidding ;D)

It would be better if it was cross-platform, but if it's not, that's still ok (as long as it runs on Linux).

Comment: Selenium is probably the most common tool: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may also want to give Requests a try:
http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html

Some people think it's a better alternative to urllib2. Mainly in that the syntax is more human-friendly. Reference: http://pydanny.blogspot.com/2011/05/python-http-requests-for-humans.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution is to use urllib2 Python standard library:

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html

It provides a simple way to make HTTP requests of all kind and parse it's responses. In C++, many big libraries (for example Qt) have HTTP libraries.

You should also combine it with curl to manipulate and send forms using these tools.